# "Смотреть с двадцать первой минуты" — о каком моменте речь?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные

Если кто-то предлагает: *вот это видео включай с 21-й минуты,* как это правильно понять? Надо включить в момент 20:xx, то есть когда целое количество минут 20, или всё же примерно **в** 21:00 (но, скорее всего, не раньше этого времени)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это напомнило мне спор, в каком году праздновать наступление 21-го века. Отсчет минут начинается с нуля, поэтому, строго говоря, первая минута — это время между 00:00:00 и 00:01:00, а 21-я минута — между 00:20:00 и 00:21:00. Но магия цифр такова, что наступление 21-го века праздновали в момент наступления 2000 года, а "смотреть с 21-й минуты" понимают как "начать смотреть в 00:21:00".

Может, предложить смотреть видео "начиная с отметки 00:20:00"? Тогда разночтений не будет точно.

Comment: Спасибо, М_Г! *...а "смотреть с 21-й минуты" понимают как начать смотреть в 00:21:00.* Вот-вот, что-то мне это подсказывало, что так понимают.

Comment: *Может, предложить смотреть видео "начиная с отметки 00:20:00"?* Ну, тут вопрос в том, станет ли так предлагать большинство. А если нет, для меня важно хотя бы научиться без сомнений понимать, что имеют в виду другие, когда они говорят, как говорят.

Comment: Только если брать мой пример, надо предлагать не в 20:00, а в 21:00. Вы ж не описались в конце первого абзаца, когда написали 21, нет? А то это очень важно.))

Comment: Артем, корректно:  "с 21-й минуты" — это "с отметки 00:20:00", но многие понимают это как "с отметки 00:21:00". Если вы переводите с  "грамотного русского" то переводите  как "с отметки 00:20:00", а если с "бытового", то переводите  как "с отметки 00:21:00".

Comment: Хм, значит, тут фишка в том, чтобы разгадать, на каком языке говорит собеседник: на "грамотном русском" или на "бытовом". :)) А это самое-то и есть сложное... :( В общем, вернулись в исходное положение: вопрос оказался так и не решённым.